# Construct the trapezoid $ABCD$ with straightedge and compass

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

> $ABCD -$ is a trapezoid. $AD||BC, AB=CD$. The diagonals of the $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at the point $P$, and the straight lines $AB$ and $CD$ intersect at the point $Q$. Points $O_1$ and $O_2$ are the centers of circles described around triangles $ABP$ and $CDP$, and $r$ is the radius of these circles.
>
> Construct the trapezoid $ABCD$ with straightedge and compass, given $O_1O_2,PQ$ and $r$.
>
> How many solutions for this problem?
>   [image]

I construct (red lines):

1) $\triangle {O_1O_2P} \left(O_1O_2, O_1P=O_2P=r\right)$

2) circles $\omega_1(O_1;r)$ and $\omega_2(O_2;r)$

3) $QP \perp O_1O_2$

*I need help here*

Comment: If you're given *points* $P$, $Q$, $O_1$, $O_2$, then there's not much to do: Draw circles $\bigcirc O_1$ and $\bigcirc O_2$, pick any $A$ on $\bigcirc O_1$, construct $B$ as the intersection of $\overleftrightarrow{AQ}$ and $\bigcirc O_1$. Then, draw circles about $Q$ that pass through $A$ and $B$; where these meet $O_2$ are $D$ and $C$, respectively. If you aren't given points, but *distances*, you can construct any $PQ$, and parallel lines at distance $|O_1O_2|/2$ on either side of $PQ$; where these lines meet $\bigcirc P$ of radius $r$ are $O_1$ and $O_2$; then, proceed as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines $BD$ and $AC$ meet at $P$ if $\angle BPA + 2\angle APP'=\pi$, where $P'$ is the other intersection point of the circles. Let $H$ be the midpoint of $AB$: by well-known theorems we have $\angle HO_1A=\angle BPA$ and $\angle AO_1P'=2\angle APP'$.

It follows that the above condition is the same as $\angle HO_1P'=\pi$, in other words: trapezoid diagonals meet at $P$ if $P'O_1$ and $AB$ are perpendicular. To construct the trapezoid you just have to draw the lines through $Q$ perpendicular to $P'O_1$ and  $P'O_2$.

Notice that this construction does not work for any value of the data: in some cases those perpendiculars don't intersect the circle and the trapezoid doesn't exist.
[image]

Comment: If draw "any" line through $Q$, then the diagonals of the$ AC$ and $BD$ NOT intersect at the point $P$

Comment: You are right: I overlooked that condition. To have $AC$ and $BD$ intersecting at $P$, line $AB$ must be perpendicular to $P'O_1$, where $P'$ is the other intersection point of the circles. I'll edit my answer to explain that.